# Error in deploying Angular WebApp from local

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

Displayed with below while deploying my angular webapp:

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Before the deployment my app worked perfectly fine in local. but after deploying it is throwing me errors.

Currently I am going through below Q&A from Microsoft.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/23282/deployed-angular-web-app-keeps-getting-you-do-not.html

But this not so helpful in my case.

If any one of you faced similar issue, can anyone assist?

Comment: I suggest you navigating to the KUDU url: https://<your app name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole and go to site\wwwroot to check if the files are contained within a directory.

Comment: What is the url you are trying to access?